# Node DynamoDB Request to object or Variable

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, callback, amazon-dynamodb

I am new to coding, so the answer might be basic. I am looking to assign the **data** from a (AWS.Request) describeTable(params = {}, callback) callback to a variable.  That way I can use the variable to conditionally check properties.

```
app.get('/chat/:eventName', function(req, res){
  var tableName = req.params.eventName;
  var dataBaseName = dbDescribe(tableName);
  if (dataBaseName.Table.TableName == tableName) {
      console.log('Table Already Exists');
    } else {
      dbCreate(tableName);
      console.log('Table Created');
    };
});

function dbDescribe(tableName) {
  dynamodb.describeTable({TableName: tableName}, function (err, data) {
        if (err) {
          console.log('Status Code = ' + err.statusCode); // an error occurred
        } else {
          console.log('DATA COMING THRU');    
          console.log(data); // successful response
        };
    }
  );
};
```

My goal was to get the "data" out of the callback function to use else where, but the regular output of dynamodb.describeTable is not the same as data, it looks like an object of all the info sent for the request.

I am still a beginner so it might just be that I am looking at it the wrong way, but I would be stoked on any tips or help.

The app is creating a database table when the event url is requested the first time. Then for future connections the info from the event will be pulled from the existing table, until the event/table is delete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use the callback, to pass result (or error if request failed) from **dbDescribe** to your method.

```
app.get('/chat/:eventName', function(req, res){
  var tableName = req.params.eventName;
  dbDescribe(tableName, function(err, dataBaseName) {
    if (dataBaseName.Table.TableName == tableName) {
      console.log('Table Already Exists');
    } else {
      dbCreate(tableName);
      console.log('Table Created');
    };
  }
});

var dbDescribe = function (tableName, cb) {
  dynamodb.describeTable({TableName: tableName}, function (err, data) {
      if (err) {
        console.log('Status Code = ' + err.statusCode); // an error occurred
        cb(err);
      } else {
        console.log('DATA COMING THRU');
        console.log(data); // successful response
        cb(null, data);
      };
    }
  );
};
```

You can get more information regarding callbacks here:

http://www.nodebeginner.org/#event-driven-callbacks

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the resource. This did work, and I am learning how callbacks work and trying to also learn how to avoid callback hell.  I wondering if using Backbone and MVC would be the over all better way to do this?